# How can I use Powershell to access a restful webservice?

Tags: json, rest, powershell

I need to integrate an existing powershell script to update it's status via a restful web service that returns json. I'm a bit new to powershell but I was able to find the System.Net.WebRequest object do something like the following.

```
$a = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://intranet/service/object/")
$a.Method = "GET"
$a.GetResponse()
```

which returns a json array of objects

```
[ {id:1}, {id:2}] // etc
```

I'm not sure where to go from here and how to parse this into a native datatype. I'd like to be able to post and delete as well.

Any pointers? And are there any json/rest libraries or command-lets?

Comment: http://duncan-cragg.org/blog/post/getting-data-rest-dialogues/

Answer (score 28):

What you want is PowerShell **3** and its *Invoke-RestMethod*, *ConvertTo-Json*, and *ConvertFrom-Json cmdlets*.  Your code will end up looking like:

$stuff = invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get;

and there shouldn't even be a need to invoke *ConvertFrom-Json* on the resulting $stuff => it's already in a usable non-string format.

As for POSTs|PUTs, simply use PowerShell hashes and arrays to structure your data and then call *ConvertTo-Json* on it before passing it to invoke-RestMethod or invoke-WebRequest:

invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Method Post -Body $objectConvertedToJson

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/hh849971.aspx for details.

Comment: You are completely correct however powershell 3 is still pretty new and not deployed where I work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), which is a part of standard .Net library.

Answer (score 2):

@Jaykul wrote a nice set of RESTful functions that are part of his Mindtouch dreamwiki script over here: http://poshcode.org/691