# Connect to JMX using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rmi, jmx

I am not a developer so please keep that in mind when reading the following message:

I need to be able to use Windows PowerShell to connect to a JMX RMI agent on a host, is this even possible ?

The example string from the java client I have been given is as below:

JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:7979/jmxrmi");

The reason for this is that I am doing other work in my PowerShell script and would like to keep it all in one place.

Thanks !

Comment: is there a .Net API for JMX? if so you could use that as you can directly access .net objects in PS or run c#\vb.net code in PS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unusual mix of two technologies, but it is possible.

On the off-chance that you are attempting to connect to a JBoss server, the quickest way may be for you to call [twiddle](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle), a command tool that will dispatch JMX requests to the target JBoss server and return the results to standard out.

Another way is to implement the [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) agent on the target servers. This will allow you to issue JMX requests using REST. Responses will also be returned in REST format which you can process in PowerShell using one of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598120/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-access-a-restful-webservice).

Thirdly, you can also deploy the [JMX-WS](http://ws-jmx-connector.java.net/) service on your target servers which will allow you to communicate with the JMX server using web-services. This [document](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/JSR262_Interop.pdf) provides some VBScript examples of this.

None of the above actually uses the JMXServiceURL syntax you outlined, and I cannot think of a way you could actually cleanly integrate this RMI based protocol into PowerShell, but hopefully one of the above will work for you.

**==========  UPDATE ==========**

There may be a way to use the RMI implementation. Take a look at [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). It is a Java Byte Code to .NET compiler. I have successfully compiled JMX/RMI java code into a .Net assembly and used it from C#. I *think* PowerShell will do the same thing.